# How to use a javascript variable inside of a link_to tag that is in a script?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a link that is going to pass some variables to another page, problem is I need to do this via javascript. Here is my javascript variable:

```
data.forEach(function(i) {

  var html = '<div><%= link_to "", "/campaigns/new", :method => :get, area: i.id %></div>';
});
```

The problem that occurs here is that `i.id` throws a syntax error since it thinks that `i` is a ruby variable.

How can I tell it to use `i` as a javascript variable?

Comment: What? You wanna use ruby code inside JavaScript that executes later?

Comment: You need to keep in mind that your rails code runs on the server, and just generates a bunch of text, which is later displayed (and executed in the case of javascript) in the user's browser.  So, you can use your rails code to create some javascript, but the rails code won't be around at javascript runtime:  just whatever javascript and html you generated.

Comment: What is `i` in this context?  Is `data` a javascript variable?

Comment: @MaxWilliams data is products, and i is a product with some information. So when I click on the link I need the id of that product to become available on another page so that I can preset some options. I would've done it differently but the person before me did it in a messed up way so now my hands are kinda tied unfortunately..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ruby code below, executes even before the JavaScript gets executed.

```
<%= link_to "", "/campaigns/new", :method => :get, area: i.id %>
```

So you cannot mix between ruby and JavaScript like how you have given your `i.id`.

JavaScript solution:

```
data.forEach(function(i) {
  var html = '<div><a href="/campaigns/new?area=' + i.id + '"></a></div>';
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I'm going to have to use url parameters instead then to solve this. Or is there some kind of workaround without the use of local storage?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz It is better to use `localStorage`. Do you have a solution with it or do you want me to code for you?

Comment: Never actually had to use it, so if you want you can post a solution with it and I'd accept the answer.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Can you tell the final HTML you would want? I strongly believe you need AJAX for the calls.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Have added the JavaScript Solution. Have a look.

Comment: I'll test the answer and get back to you.

Comment: Seems like a do-able solution to use parameters, so I guess that's the way to go. Thanks for the help, grats on almost reaching 60k.

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question, you could do like this:

```
data.forEach(function(i) {
  var html = '<div><a href="/campaigns/new" area="' + i.id + '"></a></div>';
});
```

But it's usually a better practice to store data as data attributes on your elements, and retrieve them in your JS code with a call like `element.data("area")`.